# How do I say 'It feels like' in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say 'It feels like' in Spanish? I'd like to say it in this context:

> It's 4 in the afternoon over here, but it feels like 9 in the evening.

Comment: -1. SLU is no translation service. (On the other hand, this question is identical to http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8924/how-doi-say-it-feels-like. While it's not forbidden to cross-post, I'm not sure it is ethical to do that. Anyways…)

Comment: You're supposed to post an attempt at (Spanish) translation in your question, which would then differentiate it from the German version (which should have its own attempt). My own "try" at this one is "Me siento," which I posted as a comment rather than answer, because it may be wrong. We're here to correct "self learners," not translate from scratch.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Please see my meta question: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/321/how-do-we-deal-with-how-do-you-say-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to say is

```
Pareciera que son las nueve de la noche, pero son solo las cuatro de la tarde.
```

Answer (score 5):

The Spanish verb *to feel* is *sentir*.  However, context is important, as there are two distinct senses of *sentir* in Spanish:

> *sentir* → Speaks of *what* one feels
> *sentirse* → Speaks of *how* one feels

Some examples in context:

> I feel the air. → Siento el aire.

Speaking of *what* one feels.

> I feel sad. → Me siento triste.

Speaking of *how* one feels.

---

Now, in your specific context, there's a good possibility that *to feel* isn't actually the right translation, although it depends on what you're trying to say.

The best translation, as @Envite already suggested, is probably *parecer* which means "to seem like" (related to the English word "appearance", if that helps you to remember).

> Son las 4 de la tarde por acá, pero **parecen** las 9 de la noche.
>
> It's 4 in the afternoon over here, but it **seems** like 9 in the evening.

However, if your goal is to convey a more emotional sense, that is, it truly *feels* like 9pm, on an emotional level, not simply due to viewing the position of the sun, etc, you could use the verb *sentir*:

> Son las 4 de la tarde por acá, pero **me siento** como si fueran las 9 de la noche.
>
> It's 4 in the afternoon over here, but **I feel like** it's 9 in the evening.

Lastly, you could probably use the other sense of *sentir*, and be understood, but it might seem a little bit odd and/or sloppy.

> Son las 4 de la tarde por acá, pero **se siente** como las 9 de la noche.
>
> It's 4 in the afternoon over here, but **it feels** like 9 in the evening.

Answer (score 3):

Son las cuatro de la tarde aquí, pero ***parece que*** fueran las nueve de la noche.

Comment: +1 An alternative, not very correct but quite used in very informal speak (at least in Argentina) is "es como que": `es como que fueran las nueve de la noche`.
I don't recommend you to use this, ever, but for completeness I believe it's good to know what it means.

Comment: Yes, you can hear it, but that union of two prepositions ("como que") is not correct.

Comment: @Envite: "que" is not a preposition, please!

Comment: True, it is a copulative conjunction, but it still sounds horrible

Comment: @Envite: The union of two prepositions can be correct indeed in some cases. Examples: *para con*, *de entre*, *tras de*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Es como si fueran las nueve de la noche, pero son sólo las cuatro de la tarde.

Comment: @Flimzy

"Son las 4 de la tarde por acá, pero me siento que son las 9 de la noche."

No sense at all nor heard before, possible:

Son las 4 de la tarde por acá, pero siento que son las 9 de la noche.

Answer (score 0):

> Son las cuatro de la tarde, pero *se siente* como si fueran las nueve de la noche.